# How its changed to final answer. By putting limits of integration

Tags: calculus

$4\pi\sqrt{a} \left[\frac{2}{3}(a+x^2)^{3/2}\right]$ 
on applying $x=0$ to $x=a$

In following step changed into

$\frac{8}{3}\pi a^2 \left[2\sqrt{2}-1\right]$

Doubt regarding this is the formation of term inside brackets I.e $[2\sqrt{2}-1]$ on applying values of limit of integration to 
$4\pi\sqrt{a} \left[\frac{2}{3}(a+x^2)^{3/2}\right]$

Comment: Please take the time to properly typeset your question with [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  As it is currently written, noone will be able to understand you.

Comment: OK I will ask more properly

Comment: If you want MathJax to render you have to put it between dollar signs i.e \$\$

Comment: Can you help me now . now all the terms are in Mathjax

Comment: The first expression and the second expression do not look even remotely related whatsoever.  Assuming that the limits on on the product are the same for both expressions, when treated as a function in terms of $a$ the first will be on the order of $a^{3.5a+3.5}$ while the second would be on the order of $a^{2a+2}$.

Comment: Please try to provide context or the original source of the problem.  It appears as though you are too confused to be able to accurately present or type the problem.  Another thing which confuses me here is you refer to limits of integration, but the symbol you used is for product.  Perhaps you meant to have $\int$ instead of $\prod$?

Comment: The problem is regarding finding surface area of revolution revolving about x axis

Comment: Q: Find area of the surface generated by revolving about the x axis , the arc of the parabola y^2 =4ax from (0,0) to the point x=a    I'm stuck with final step of the problem , this solved using integration method to find area of revolution of solids

Comment: I reconstructed what you did based on your comment (which should have been part of the original question!) and fixed some of the obvious transcription errors (the symbol for circumference/diameter is $\pi,$ not $\prod,$ and the $3/2$ power of something is written `^{3/2}`, not `^3/2`--the second version means cube the number and then divide by $2$). However, I did _not_ correct the exponent of $x,$ which also is wrong and which makes the "following step" not work. Fix the exponent and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> "*Q: Find area of the surface generated by revolving about the x axis , the arc of the parabola y^2 =4ax from (0,0) to the point x=a*"

The question in the comments section at least makes sense and we can answer that.  The question asked in the original post is still horribly unclear.

The circumference of a circle is $2\pi r$ where $r$ is the radius.  As we are rotating around the $x$-axis, the radius will depend on the value of $x$.  The radius at the particular $x$ value is $2\sqrt{ax}$.  To get the surface area, we integrate then $$\int\limits_{0}^{a}2\pi\cdot 2\sqrt{ax}~\text{d}x$$

This should be a routine straightforward calculation at this point.  We can factor some to make it look easier:

$$=4\pi\sqrt{a}\int\limits_{0}^{a}\sqrt{x}~\text{d}x=4\pi\sqrt{a}~\left[\frac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}\right]^{x=a}_{x=0}=4\pi\sqrt{a}\left(\frac{2a^{3/2}}{3}-0\right)$$

which finally simplifies to be

$$\frac{8\pi a^2}{3}$$